# PHP tab delimited text file into array

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a huge text file structured like so:

```
email 1
email 14
email 1
email 244
email 232
email 23
email 1
```

I'm trying to pull the text file into an array, where I can then remove all emails that so not have a number one. Right now I'm limiting to the first 20, all of which have the number 1, but the only thing I'm getting in my array is the number 1. When I spit out the number of items in the line it says 1.

```
$file = "list.txt";// Your Temp Uploaded file
$cols = array();
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);

$fh = fopen($file, 'r');
$i = 0;

while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t") !== false) {
  $cols[] = $line;

  if($i == 19) { break; }
    $i++;
  }

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cols); 
echo "</pre>";

Array
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 1
[2] => 1
[3] => 1
[4] => 1
[5] => 1
[6] => 1
[7] => 1
[8] => 1
[9] => 1
[10] => 1
[11] => 1
[12] => 1
[13] => 1
[14] => 1
[15] => 1
[16] => 1
[17] => 1
[18] => 1
[19] => 1
)
```

I've tried changing `\t` to `\n` but that didn't change the result. If I can do this all in one step that would be better, check the second item in the row and if it's a one then add the first item (email) into the array. Otherwise don't. At this point I'll take what I can get! Any ideas or suggestions?

---

I now am getting the items in the array, but it's merging the columns into one array item:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => EMAIL    1
    )
)
```

Is there a way for me to spit out the columns into separate keys? So:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => EMAIL
        [1] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: check if the delimiter is `Tab` (\t) or `Space`

Comment: @cfox Based on your update:  if its putting them into one column then its not tab delimited `\t` try using a space now ' '

Comment: I actually had changed the original to the space and had to change it back to the tab. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap your while statement with more `( )`

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t") !== false) {
```

should be

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, "\t")) !== false) {
```

Comment: This fixed it, but created a new issue :) Accepting your answer since this was the main issue.

Comment: @cfox Whats the new issue?

Comment: Updated the original question.